# trigger denying update for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a test in my trigger, which works fine for 1 row, but I cannot figure out how to get it to deny the update should multiple rows get edited.

Current code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER forecasting.sitenametest
ON forecasting.sitenames
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        return

      SET nocount ON;

      DECLARE @test INT
      DECLARE @SiteTest CHAR(8)

      SELECT @SiteTest = i.sitename FROM inserted i

      SET @test = CASE
                WHEN @SiteTest = 'NA      ' THEN 1
                WHEN OtherTest..            THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END

      IF @test = 0
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK
          RAISERROR('Site code not in correct format',16,1)
      END
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about test with the rowcount again:

```
CREATE TRIGGER forecasting.sitenametest ON forecasting.sitenames
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            RETURN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT  *
        FROM    inserted
        WHERE   sitename IN ( 'NA      ', 'Other Examples' )

        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK
                RAISERROR('Site code not in correct format',16,1)
            END

    END
```

Comment: The secondary tests aren't as simple as being able to use `IN`. Also, shouldn't the test check against the previous rowcount.

Comment: Well how would I have known that based on your question?  @@ROWCOUNT returns the previous row count.

Comment: The first test makes sure something is updated, so it's not triggered with an `update stuff when 1=0`, but I couldn't figure out how to make the test work with more than 1 row is altered.  Your answer did push me in the right direction, as I was able to do a `Select * from inserted` and save that rowcount, and then the select statement you provided allowed me to check if the rowcounts were equal.